# Is there a way to deny user to remove certain account in Android?

Tags: android, account, user-accounts, accountmanager

I have an account added programmatically. I want to prevent this account from removal.

Is there some API to make this account non-removable?

Answer (score 1):

If you own the device, you can use device policy to prevent a lot of actions like that (although it can be worked around with physical access, especially if the boot loader is unlocked).  If you're just a random app downloaded from the play store, no.

Comment: My app is device owner. But I don't see any appropriate API in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html